# How to develop an app for Sony Bravia Internet TV?

Tags: sony, smart-tv

My question is specifically for non android TVs. Sony did not specified much about TVs at developers.sony.com.

The netflix and youtube apps are already built into that. I would like to know whether it is possible to write my own app and add into that list? I would also like to know what OS are internet TVs are running ?